# How to send django Inmemoryuploadfile (image file)to google drive without saving the image in local directory

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm working on a project to integrate Google Drive to a Django web application to view and upload files to Google Drive.

I was using `Drive REST API` for this requirement.
Using the API, I tried uploading all type of files to GD (Google Drive).

All the files are getting uploaded successfully. But only `.txt` file type was able to open and download perfectly. All other types such as `.docs`, `.xls`, `.jpef`, etc. are not getting opened and downloaded. Opening these files on GD throws an error with `No Preview available`.

Can any one please help me with how to upload, view and download the `.doc`, `.xls`, image file?

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to upload those files? What are the settings you are giving to the API for those files?